# sbt-native-packager is it possible to use local filesystem docker image as base image

Tags: scala, docker, filesystems, dockerfile, sbt-native-packager

currently using sbt-native-packager v 1.2.1 which by default uses the openjdk base docker image as described at http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html

**Environment Settings**

"dockerBaseImage
The image to use as a base for running the application. It should include binaries on the path for chown, mkdir, have a discoverable java binary, and include the user configured by daemonUser (daemon, by default)."

I was wondering if it's possible to use a local image from the filesystem instead simply pointing to something like "./my-Dockerfile" ?

Comment: If as it seems it requires an image name rather than image spec (name or build context), then no

Comment: This is not SBT native-packager related. If docker supports it, native-packager supports it.